# Run Docker container from removable media

Tags: docker

I want to put a Docker image onto a USB HD and then be able to plug that into any [Linux] machine that has Docker and run the image. How would I go about doing that?

So far, I've discovered that you can "export" a Docker image into a flat file, but it appears you can't *do* anything with it until you "import" it again. That's no good. My ultimate goal is to run this stuff from a boot CD, which obviously won't have any writable storage to "import" the data into.

Comment: Docker needs a registry for images, either local or remote. How did you plan to let docker see the image? I think what you ask for is not possible. Maybe have a shell script to import the image to the local registry automatically and start the image. This is how we deploy our images to remote IoT devices when there is no access to the central repo.

Comment: AFAIK Docker uses a layered file system to store containers - so you won't be able to copy just the layer of 'your' container - you will have to copy all layers that it depends on - I guess that is what import/export does. So I doubt that your scenario is feasible. You would have to copy the whole 'graph' directory, but I do not know if that is doable.

Comment: Is this what you need? https://blog.docker.com/2015/03/tiny-docker-operating-systems/

Comment: Is it possible to run the Docker daemon in such a way that it puts *all* its files on an external device rather than... wherever it usually puts them? Would it then see the same images and containers on every machine?

Comment: As I mentioned: the place where docker keeps all container image data is determined by the setting 'graph' in the settings-file (at least on Docker for Windows, which I am using exclusively). Unfortunately I can't help you with the other parts of your question(s).

Answer (score 0):

So remember that Docker is a service running on your [Linux] machine.
What you can do is are the following options:

1. Build and run the Dockerfile located on your USB Drive

   **docker build -t my_image --file /path/to/Dockerfile/on/usb/drive . && docker container run -d my_image**
2. Create a docker-compose file and run the docker-compose from the Dockerfile on your USB Drive

   **docker-compose up -d --build -f /path/to/Dockerfile/on/usb/drive**

In the end, the container will always run on the host machine, but you can take that USB drive to any machine and run the Dockerfile anywhere

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it appears there's two main locations that the Docker daemon uses:

- `/var/lib/docker` holds all the Docker images.
- `/var/run/docker` holds... actually I'm not sure.

The solution I came up with is this:

- Delete (!!) the `/var/lib/docker` folder.
- Create a symlink named `/var/lib/docker` which points to where you *actually* want the data stored.
- Then (and only then) start the Docker daemon.

This seems to result in Docker storing its data where you tell it to. In particular, if you symlink to a folder on an external USB device, Docker will store its state there. You can then repeat this procedure on another machine (maybe one without Internet access) and access the image(s).

Mind you, this stores the *entire* state of the Docker daemon, not just one image. But I haven't yet found a way around that.

You also wouldn't want to do this to a "real" computer; I want this for a boot CD, where next time you reboot, all the changes to the filesystem will just disappear again.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: It's possible to run two Docker daemons on the same host, and to pass images between them. So you could start one daemon running on USB storage, load the necessary image(s) into it, and then on another machine start Docker running on the same USB device.

To run an alternative Docker daemon, you need the following incantations:

```
containerd \
  --state-dir /mnt/Docker/containerd \
  --listen unix:///mnt/Docker/containerd.sock

dockerd \
  --pidfile /mnt/Docker/dockerd.pid \
  --data-root /mnt/Docker/Data \
  --exec-root /mnt/Docker/Exec \
  --containerd /mnt/Docker/containerd.sock \
  --host unix:///mnt/Docker/dockerd.sock
```

For this to work, the directory `/mnt/Docker` needs to already exist. The other files, sockets and directories appear to get created automatically.

Both `containerd` and `dockerd` accept a `--debug` option that makes them output a lot more info to the console. Both of these are daemons, so the commands above never return.

Once the new `dockerd` is running, you can talk to it as normal if you manually specify the socket:

```
docker --host unix:///mnt/Docker/dockerd.sock info
```

You might want to define that as a shell alias to save some typing.

You can copy an image from the "normal" Docker daemon to the new one you just created like so:

```
docker save ubuntu:latest | docker --host unix:///mnt/Docker/dockerd.sock load
```